# Mikro ORM: properties are having any type on orm.em.create();

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mikro-orm

I am have created a product entity, and using the ORM to generate fake data. But however, the em.create is using any as the type of entity's properties. Also, em.create has made all properties optional including the ones which I explicitly set to be required with `!` mark (`Product.name` for eg). I cannot see what am I doing wrong. Here's the code

### Product Entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id!: ObjectId;

  @SerializedPrimaryKey()
  id!: string;

  @Property()
  name!: string;

  @Property()
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

  @Property({ onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt: Date = new Date();

  @Property()
  description!: string;

  @Property()
  image!: string;

  @Property()
  price!: number;

  @Property()
  tags: string[] = [];

  @Property()
  quantity: number = 0;
}
```

### The types by em.create()

[image: The types by em.create]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That is just the input type, the returned entity will be typed correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to make the types strict by some generics or something? Or at least make typescript give warnings?

Comment: I have checked the typings of EntityData<>, which were:
`export declare type EntityData<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | any; 
} & Dictionary`

I changed it to 
`export declare type EntityData<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; 
} & Dictionary`

and the types are back. Any specific reason to include `| any`?